# My company website is not accessible via Static IP address

Tags: wireless-networking, router, static-ip

I am using static IP for internet connection.My company webpage is not accessible when I connected by WIFI.But, when my mac address cleared from server by the internet provider and When I configured same static IP in the network(IPv4),then It allows to browse company webpage.

Wanted to know reason behind this weird behavior.

DLINK Router:600L

Comment: The configuration settings of D-Link routers themselves sometimes exhibit weird behavior without any connection to your company's website or your internet service provider. If this is the case in your situation then you're stuck with it, but at least it works now.

Comment: Thanks Karel,Could you tell me purchasing new router can help in this situation.

Comment: Call your ISP. Sometimes if you buy one of their routers your ISP will tell you how to setup their router on the phone. In case the router is still OK and you missed some weird setting on it. My ISP has the router setup instructions on an answering machine so you can get the router setup instructions via phone 24 hrs. a day.

Comment: They told me that your current router is blocking company website,trying new router is only the solution left.

Comment: For testing purposes only: If you use an Ethernet cable and bypass the WiFi router, connecting directly to the internet service provider's connection, does the problem persist? If it does, your ISP or the DNS server you use has a problem; change your DNS Server to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.4.4 and retry. Let us know the result.

Comment: By using Ethernet cable directly,resolved issued.But internet is limited to the particular device.Also,It required to deletion of MAC address from Service provider.The solution Changing existing DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 works for me.Thanks everyone for your kind help.